# Gnuradio(3.7.9): how to add a qt widget such as slider to the flowgraph?(new version has no support the pyqwt)

Tags: python, pyqt, gnuradio, openembedded

**What I want to do?**

I want to make a simple program that show the radio frequency base on the openembedded layer [meta-sdr](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-sdr/) using [gnuradio](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/23355/) and [rtl-sdr](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/23501/) recipe. The program was running on the beaglebone black.

**My problem:**

I have run `bitbake core-image-sato` with gnuradio and rtl-sdr successfully. But when I run the result python file on my target, it said that `no module named PyQt4.Qwt5` which is because I use the QT GUI Range as a slider to control the radio frequency. I found that the recipe gnuradio in [meta-sdr](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-sdr/) have droped the PyQwt [meta-sdr github issue: PyQWT is no longer needed for GNU Radio widgets](https://github.com/balister/meta-sdr/issues/29).

How can I implement the slider in flowgraph using the new version gnuradio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQWT wasn't removed as dependency of GNU Radio out of fun, it was removed because it's no longer used anywhere – the current QT GUI range sliders are pure Qt, no QWT. If you use a current GNU Radio recipe, and use current GNU Radio to generate your flow graph from GRC (if you're doing that), then you won't need Qwt.

Comment: Thank you very much, I produced that python file which contain `import PyQt4.Qwt5 as Qwt` on my host(Ubuntu14.04) indeed, that gnuradio version contains the PyQWT, according to you idea, I need to produce it on my beaglebone?

Comment: No, as I said, you need to use a current version of GNU Radio on your PC. Update that, and you should be fine.

Comment: Except that Qt sliders don't seem to be installed by default with the current version, under Ubuntu.  Gnuradio has presented more bugs / required more workarounds for me than any other software system I've used.

Comment: This is not true. I know the Ubuntu installation very well, and they're definitely there.